# Is there anything wrong with throwing exceptions in the try block?

Tags: c#

Is it a good design practice to code a `try-catch` block as follows? That is, use a `throw` in the try block and then catch it in the catch block.

```
try
{
  if (someCondition){

      throw new Exception("Go the the associated catch block!");

     }
}

catch(Exception ex)
{
      logError("I was thrown in the try block above");
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that. You can also throw different type of Exception and use different catch for each type.

Answer (score 3):

There are times when you might want to - for example, if you're using ado.net, it has a habit of throwing *everything* as a `SqlException` - you might want to catch some of these, and handle them, whilst leaving the handling of others to another level. In this case, you'd have to catch the SqlException, see if you can handle it, and rethrow it if not.

Answer (score 3):

Exceptions are for **exception**al circumstances. It should not be used as control of flow logic but if there is a edge case that needs to be handled if it does come up there is nothing wrong in doing it.

I have done this myself throwing a [InvalidDataException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.invaliddataexception.aspx) in my code if the data I am reading is not what I am expecting.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is not bad design, if it is the shortest writable method. But beware, that throwing an excaption usually takes approximetaly 1 ms to catch. In that matter it is a performance issue.

Comment: it's not the throwing that is expensive.  It's constructing the `Throwable` that is expensive because that involves capturing the stack.  If you can avoid that step, for example by pre-allocating the exception and sharing it across multiple throws, then it is quite efficient.

Comment: @MikeSamuel Interesting, can you provide a link to some example code of a good way of doing that?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, my [RFC 2445](http://code.google.com/p/google-rfc-2445/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/ical/iter/Generators.java#68) implementation uses exceptions as non-local transfer of control to ensure that bad cases like "every February 30th" don't deny service.  The [singleton exception](http://code.google.com/p/google-rfc-2445/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/ical/iter/Generator.java#60) uses `setStackTrace(new StackTraceElement[0])` to do away with the cruft stack.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, actually I just realized that this question was C#, not Java.  In C#, it is the other way around.  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace(v=vs.71).aspx) says "By default, the stack trace is captured immediately before an exception object is thrown" which means that throwing an exception is expensive, unless there's a way to override that default.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, perhaps overriding the `StackTrace` property as described in ["`Exception.StackTrace` property"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace.aspx) allows one to avoid stacktrace capture.

Comment: @MikeSamuel Not to turn this in to a discussion but that would not work, the default constructor for `StackTrace` will still be called so it will still be expensive.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, but in .NET, stack traces are not fetched at construct time.  The goal of overriding would be to prevent the stack trace fetch when thrown.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, you should throw exception in an usual situation and is better your own exception rather than a general one.

Answer (score 1):

It is completely dependant on what you're trying to achieve. On the whole its best to avoid over-use of try-catch blocks, not least because they are slow. Lots of try-catch blocks can make your code look messy and hard to follow.

You need to consider why the exception would be thrown, is it an unexpected error, a bug, or an expected error? If its an expected error then you should try to code around it, without using a try-catch.

Answer (score 1):

If someCondition represents a true error state, then yes. There is no problem with that. However, please don't use it to control program flow. Nothing drives me more nuts than seeing an exception thrown when one could just exit the scope. It also has the potential to compromise the proper handling of real exceptions in your code.